# EXPECT_CALL without mock in Google Test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

Is there any way to test a function call via GoogleTest for c++ without creating mock object, e.g. we have the following production code:

```
if (a)
    method(x);
```

I would like to test whether the `method` will be called in the case `a` is True and `a` is False. I would like to construct a test that does exactly the same what Google Test's EXPECT_CALL does, but EXPECT_CALL works only with the mock object's method. In my case I would prefer not to use a mock (there is no need to create any object).

Comment: And `EXPECT_CALL` comes from where? Does what? Please don't assume people use or know your tools. Be explicit and detailed.

Comment: I have corrected my question. Thank you for correcting too general way of wording.

Comment: Is this still not possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As state [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#mocking-free-functions),

> It's possible to use Google Mock to mock a free function (i.e. a C-style function or a static method). You just need to rewrite your code to use an interface (abstract class).

Their *"It's possible"* is misleading, as you have to rewrite code to use class (abstract, or provided by template), and so no longer use free functions.

Comment: So other words testing of the free function is impossible via GoogleTest?

Comment: It is what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fake a free function, you may want to look into the [Fake Function Framework (fff)](https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff).  It allows you to replace free functions with fake implementations that can be used in a similar way to GoogleMock.

It works seamlessly with GoogleMock and GoogleTest.

Comment: As I understand, libraries linking should be changed to not include real library but the fake one.Am I right ?