# Gtest: mocking free function in a constructor

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, mocking, googletest

I read a lot of documentation related to Gtest mocking (e.g., https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md, "Mocking Free Functions"), but couldn't find the solution for the following problem:

> source.cpp

```
H::H()
{
    // some code1
    if (to_be_mocked(id) != 0) { // some code2 }
    // some code3
}

H& H::get_instance()
{
    static H s;
    return s;
}
```

> unit_test.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

#include "source.h"

TEST(Source, Constructor)
{
    // What to write here to mock function "to_be_mocked"?
    H& inst = H::get_instance();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

So, I need to test the whole code in the `H`'s constructor and mock function `to_be_mocked` which is defined in a different translation unit. How can I do it from `unit_test.cpp`?

Comment: `H::get_instance` is not a free function. The "free" means "not a member of any class". In your case it *is* a (static) member.

Comment: @StoryTeller Function `to_be_mocked` is a free function.

Comment: It is not really possible see [expect-call-without-mock-in-google-test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50751196/2684539).

Comment: `to_be_mocked`, good name, though too hidden.

Comment: @Jarod42 So, does that mean that I have to change the source code? I don't have any permission to do so. Actually, we shouldn't change source code in order to write unit test for it.

Comment: @DavidHovsepyan: Yes. else you have to use other kind of mocking as substitute source/library, or other ugly things...

Comment: *"Actually, we shouldn't change source code in order to write unit test for it"* - This assumes the code was written with testability in mind. No offense, but the fact you *need* to mock `to_be_mocked` implies `H` wasn't written like that.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes. Unfortunately the code has been written about 25 years ago.

Comment: As an alternative. Since unit testing is all about comparing inputs to expected outputs. Instead of mocking that function, can't you just choose a clever `id` for testing?

Comment: @StoryTeller No, I can't, because `to_be_mocked` function finds an IP address in some container by the given `id` and the container is empty in this point, because it should be filled in some other ways. Maybe I can fill the container with the proper IPs, but in this case will it be unit test or integration test?

Comment: Honestly, I think you shouldn't sweat too much about how to call it. If "mocking" the container is easier then go ahead and do that. There are many conflicting definitions for "unit" and "integration" tests.

Answer (score 2):

[Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI) to the rescue!

DI is a key enabler of mocking. Specifically, you can use the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to inject the dependency into this object so you can sub it out at test time.

### Option 1: Constructor Injection

The simplest version of this would be to pass in a functor to your constructor and call that where you are currently calling `to_be_mocked()`.

In this case your class would look something like:

```
class H 
{
    std::function<bool(int)> _to_be_mocked;
public:
    H( std::function<bool(int)> fn ) 
        : _to_be_mocked( std::move(fn) ) 
    {
        uses_mockable( 42 ); 
    }

    void uses_mockable( int id ) 
    {
        if( _to_be_mocked(id) ) { ... }
    }

    ...
};

void MyTest() 
{
    auto my_mock_fn = ...;
    auto h = H{ my_mock_fn };

    // Set expectations to assert that my_mock_fn is used correctly
    // and that the caller behaves properly in response to its return values
}
```

DI doesn't play well with globals/singletons because you can't (easily) inject dependencies at construction time, which is one reason why they are discouraged.

### Option 2: Property Injection

If you can't change the singleton to a regular instance or control its initial construction separately where you can inject a dependency, then you can use property-based injection where you expose the functor publicly (or selectively via something like the [Attorney-Client idiom](http://www.drdobbs.com/friendship-and-the-attorney-client-idiom/184402053)) and then set it when you need to.

In this case, your class would look like:

```
class H 
{
    std::function<bool(int)> _to_be_mocked;

    static bool default_to_be_mocked( int ) { ... }

public:

    H() 
        : _to_be_mocked( default_to_be_mocked ) // Use stand-alone function for default
    { /* can't use mock here */ }

    // Could restrict accessibility here with Attorney-Client idiom or friendship
    void set_to_be_mocked( std::function<bool(int)> fn ) 
    { 
        _to_be_mocked = std::move( fn ); 
    }

    void uses_mockable( int id ) 
    {
        if( _to_be_mocked && _to_be_mocked( id ) ) { ... }
    }

    ...
};

void MyTest() 
{
    auto my_mock_fn = ...;
    auto& h = H::get_instance();
    // ...
    h.set_to_be_mocked( my_mock_fn );

    // Set expectations to assert that my_mock_fn is used correctly
    // and that the caller behaves properly in response to its return values
}
```

This approach won't work if you need to *call* `_to_be_mocked()` in your constructor, so you'd have to go with the former approach (preferred) OR go with Option 3.

### Option 3: Poor Man's DI by Global Variable

If you can't use either of the above approaches, you could use "poor man's DI" by using Yet Another Global (sin begets sin, they say). One way of doing this in your case without changing the calling code is to rename `to_be_mocked()` to something like `to_be_mocked_impl()` and create a global functor named `to_be_mocked`:

```
bool to_be_mocked_impl( int id ) { ... } // used to be called to_be_mocked(int)

// Global instance that can be swapped out for testing.
// Defaults to the normal runtime function.
// Might use a raw function pointer instead of a std::function if you prefer.
auto to_be_mocked = std::function<bool(int)>{ to_be_mocked_impl };

class H 
{
public:
    H() 
    {
        uses_mockable( 42 ); 
    }

    void uses_mockable( int id ) 
    {
        if( to_be_mocked(id) ) { ... }
    }

    ...
};

void MyTest() 
{
    auto my_mock_fn = ...;
    to_be_mocked = my_mock_fn; // Sets global ... blah!!

    auto& h = H::get_instance();

    // Set expectations to assert that my_mock_fn is used correctly
    // and that the caller behaves properly in response to its return values
}
```

This compounds the situation with globals/singletons, so I wouldn't recommend it unless you have to for unreasonable reasons.

PS, There was an [episode of CppCast on Dependency Injection](http://cppcast.com/2019/01/kris-jusiak/) that talked about the experimental [[Boost.]DI library](https://boost-experimental.github.io/di/) that may be useful here.